# Products of matrices of a certain form

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, co.combinatorics

Are $n \times n$ matrices of the form
$$\pmatrix{1&1&1&1 \cr x&1&1&1 \cr x&x&1&1 \cr x&x&x&1}$$
studied anywhere? I am interested in the structure of the matrix obtained by multiplying a bunch of these together.

Comment: These are special Töplitz matrices.  Maybe you should look at their inverses: it has -1/(x-1) on the main diagonal, 1/(x-1) on the superdiagonal and x/(x-1) in the lower left corner.  All the other entries are zero.

Comment: They also happen to be semiseparable.

Comment: Thank you Martin and Federico. $1/(1-x)$ resonates well with my problem!